# Задача про роботов

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть задача и я не совсем понимаю как ее решить, понял основной принцип но не до конца.

Задача: В сервисе починки роботов очень важно соблюдать порядок. Главный механик любит, чтобы все роботы стояли друг за другом — сначала только сломанные (если они есть), а потом исправные (если они есть).
По ночам роботы всё время гуляют по ангару, и к утру порядок, установленный главным механиком, нарушается. Механик решил наказывать роботов, которые нарушают порядок, и удалять из очереди. Но роботы взбунтовались и требуют равноправия — если уж удалять из очереди, то равное количество исправных и сломанных роботов.
Сломанные роботы обозначаются буквой B (broken), исправные — буквой W (working).
Есть строка из букв B и W. Надо удалить наименьшее и равное количество сломанных и исправных роботов так, чтобы в очереди сначала стояли только сломанные, а потом только исправные. Может оказаться, что одних или других нет. Общее количество роботов в очереди не превышает 10 000.
Выведи количество удалённых роботов и очередь, которая получилась после удаления нарушивших правило роботов.
Если в очереди никого не осталось, выведи "НИКОГО НЕ ОСТАЛОСЬ".

Поначалу показалось что понял как ее решить, но когда увидел ввод/вывод то немного сломался.

**Ввод:BWBWWBW
Вывод: 2 BBWWW**

**Ввод: WBBWWBBW
Вывод:  4 BBWW**

Не могу понять как определить какое количество роботов надо исключить, вроде бы если 'перед ночью' (на примере 2 ввода) было **BBBBWWWW**, то после вывода идет **BBWW**. Надеюсь кто нибудь объяснит мне как это сделать)

Comment: *Ввод: WBBWWBBW Вывод: 6 BW* ??? сфига бы? **W**BBWW**BBW** и получаем "4 BBWW"

Comment: А вы не из [одной группы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1501823/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)? **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, [отредактируйте вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1502173/edit) и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. **Приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу**

Comment: @SwaD , я же написал что вызвало у меня трудности. Кода нет по тому что нет понимания как отбираются роботы на удаление из очереди. Я не прошу решить задачу, я хочу чтоб мне просто объяснили как это происходит.

Comment: Отложите код в сторону и возьмите бумажку. На ней порисуйте, как бы вы определяли, сколько роботов надо исключить и как роботов отсортировать. Если из ваших примеров, то: Перед В не должно быть W, это нарушение. B должно стоять в начале или после B, но не перед W. Вот такие коллизии ищите, берете минимум и удаляете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество роботов для удаления *d(s)* обладает следующими свойствами:

1. *d() = 0* - нет роботов - нечего удалять,
2. *d(B...) = d(...)* - сломанный робот слева на результат не влияет,
3. *d(...W) = d(...)* - рабочий робот справа на результат не влияет,
4. *d(W...B) = 2 + d(...)* - рабочий слева, сломанный справа составляют одну пару.

*d(BWBWWBW) =<sub>2</sub> d(WBWWBW) =<sub>3</sub> d(WBWWB) =<sub>4</sub> 2 + d(BWW) =<sub>2</sub>*

*=<sub>2</sub> 2 + d(WW) =<sub>3</sub> 2 + d(W) =<sub>3</sub> 2 + d() =<sub>1</sub> 2*

*d(WBBWWBBW) =<sub>3</sub> d(WBBWWBB) =<sub>4</sub> 2 + d(BBWWB) =<sub>2</sub> 2 + d(BWWB) =<sub>2</sub>*

*=<sub>2</sub> 2 + d(WWB) =<sub>4</sub> 4 + d(W) =<sub>3</sub> 4 + d() =<sub>1</sub> 4*

Эта функция вычисляется за линейное время. Из неё же можно сделать функцию, которая вернёт правильный строй после удаления. Но это будет в другом ответе.